# Store Generic list in Cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I want to store my generic list into cookies because session expire again and again when i change code and rebuild. i want to store my list in cookies so that cookies is not expire when i rebuild.

How to Store My generic list into Cookies.?

I tried this :

```
List<EvaluationModel> evalModel = (List<EvaluationModel>)Session["ESearch"];
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("evalModel");
cookie.Value = evalModel;
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24);
Response.SetCookie(cookie);
```

But its say `cannot implicitly convert type generic.list to string.`

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any generic list in your code and "not working" is not a description that is good enough.

Comment: "EvaluationModel" seems to be a class and not a list. Does that class contain a list? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cookie is just string data; the only way to do that would be to serialize it as a string (xml, json, base-64 of arbitrary binary, whatever) and again deserializing it back when you need it.

Also serializing a generic list means it will create a big string which will be running to and fro the client/server. Hence your request/response will be heavy and hence slow.

IMO, caching this at the server is the correct thing; don't put this in a cookie.